# Why I get unexpected result error when testing REST API?

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

When testing the REST API, an unexpected result was returned:

REST API Endpoint: https://valbrunpro.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post?context=edit
REST API Response: (404) Not Found

Disabled cloudflare to see if it was inadvertently blocking the Rest API. Disabled cache plugins to see if they were causing the conflict but none of these fixed the issue. Still receiving error message in site health about the Rest Api.

Needed to know how to authenticate my site with REST API through .htacess file?

Comment: have you tried to change the apache2.conf from  `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` under the <Directory /var/www/> tag?

Comment: AllowOverride None was the cause of my problem. Thanx!